# C++ Не видит путь из-за кирилицы

Tags: c++

Написал прогу для создания папок на серверах но столкнулся с проблемойю
Если пути имеют русскую кириллицу программа запускается но ничего не происходит затем выдается ошибка: ""terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
what():  filesystem error: Cannot convert character sequence: Illegal byte sequence

Process returned -1073740791 (0xC0000409)   execution time : 2.060 s
Press any key to continue.

Если я использую путь к примеру fs::path path = ("D://test//Vacancy"); То все отлично копируется.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <filesystem>

   using namespace std;
   namespace fs = std::filesystem;

   int main()
   {

   setlocale ( LC_ALL , "" ) ;

   fs::path path = ("D://Тест//Vacancy");

   const auto copyOptions =  fs::copy_options::recursive ;

    fs::copy("Vacancy", path ,copyOptions);
    cout << "Готово" << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `fs::path path{L"D:\\Тест\\Vacancy"};`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49781951/21493925

Comment: *"Если пути имеют русскую кириллицу"* - покажите какой именно путь не работает.

Comment: fs::path path = ("D://Тест//Vacancy"); Именно этот путь не работает но если написать fs::path path = ("D://test//Vacancy"); так то работает.

Comment: fs::path path{L"D:\\Тест\\Vacancy"};  не помогло вывалилось куча ошибок.

Comment: Я пробовал через string не помогло.Оказалось string не поддерживает кирилиццу.

Comment: *"вывалилось куча ошибок"* - вместо этого стоило бы привести сами ошибки, и еще то, как это все собирается, чтобы получился [mcve].

Comment: C:\code\work2_copy\main.cpp:15:15: error: converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence
   15 | fs::path path{L"D:\\Тест\\Vacancy"};
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\code\work2_copy\main.cpp:15:35: error: no matching function for call to 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::path(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
   15 | fs::path path{L"D:\\Тест\\Vacancy"};

Comment: Ошибки следует приводить в самом вопросе, чтобы не получалась каша. И то, как это собиралось, тоже надо обязательно указывать. Ваша цель - чтобы ошибку смогли воспроизвести у себя читающие вопрос. Сейчас даже непонятно, откуда такое вообще может вылезать, в сообщениях об ошибках отсутствуют референсные идентификаторы, типа `C1999`.

Comment: Сами попробуйте ставить код если у Вас есть такая возможность и вы поймете что это капец какой-то.

Comment: Потому что текст следует добавлять в сам вопрос, а не в комментарии к нему.

Answer (score -1):

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <filesystem>

  using namespace std;
  namespace fs = std::filesystem;

  int main()
  {
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
  fs::path path = (u8"//server//Папка//папка2//папка3//Vacancy");

  const auto copyOptions =  fs::copy_options::recursive ;

  fs::copy("Vacancy", path ,copyOptions);
  wcout << L"Готово " << endl;
  return 0;
  }
```

Да пока копирование без проверки папки но сейчас допишу.
Да и еще пути нельзя  копировать и вставлять их нужно прописывать в ручную. В зависимости вашей IDE.